# windows phone Virtualized Canvas for more efficient and flexible list box, is it a right approach or not?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

background:
I'm working on the app. One of the pages is the news feed. The data in news is dynamic: it may contain several text blocks, many images and layout is calculated for each news item based on content.

Since it is not possible (I don't see how) to make it work with ListBox/DataTemplate/Binding I went to lower level approach and tried to implement Virtualized Canvas:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16063542/MyVirtualizingPanel.cs

Idea is simple:

every contained item implements:

public interface IVirtualizable
    {
        void ChangeState(VirtualizableState newState);

```
    VirtualizableState CurrentState { get; }

    double FixedHeight { get; }

    FrameworkElement View { get; }

    Thickness Margin { get; }
}
```

-panel should be put into the ScrollViewer and initialized:

```
public void InitializeWithScrollViewer(ScrollViewer _scrollViewer)
    {
        _listScrollViewer = _scrollViewer;
        EnsureBoundToScrollViewer();
    }

    protected void EnsureBoundToScrollViewer()
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = _listScrollViewer;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("VerticalOffset");
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        this.SetBinding(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, binding);


    }
```

Panel implements AddItems method:

public void AddItems(IEnumerable _itemsToBeAdded)
        {

```
        double topMargin = 0;


        foreach (var itemToBeAdded in _itemsToBeAdded)
        {

            itemToBeAdded.View.Margin = new Thickness(0, itemToBeAdded.Margin.Top + topMargin, 0, 0);

            _virtualizableItems.Add(itemToBeAdded);


            topMargin += itemHeightIncludingMargin;
        }

        Height = topMargin;

    }
```

and then based on changes in scroll position it loads and unloads items:

private void LoadItemsInSegment(Segment segment, VirtualizableState desiredState)
        {
            for (int i = segment.LowerBound; i <= segment.UpperBound; i++)
            {
                var item = _virtualizableItems[i];

```
            item.ChangeState(desiredState);

            if (!Children.Contains(item.View))
            {
                Children.Add(item.View);
            }
        }
    }
```

private void LoadItemsInSegment(Segment segment, VirtualizableState desiredState)
        {
            for (int i = segment.LowerBound; i <= segment.UpperBound; i++)
            {
                var item = _virtualizableItems[i];

```
            item.ChangeState(desiredState);

            if (!Children.Contains(item.View))
            {
                Children.Add(item.View);
            }
        }
    }

 private void UnloadItemsInSegment(Segment segment)
    {
        for (int i = segment.LowerBound; i <= segment.UpperBound; i++)
        {
            var item = _virtualizableItems[i];


            Children.Remove(item.View);

            item.ChangeState(VirtualizableState.Unloaded);

        }
    }
```

More or less, it works. However, as the layout becomes more complex and gets several images, the scrolling performance becomes somewhat poor. In addition to that there are noticeable issues when rendering from time to time: suddenly (for one frame) elements appear mispositioned, it looks like a "blink", don't know how to explain it.  Anyway, my question: is this approach initially has a flaw? 
Or should I continue trying to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your virtualizing panel virtualize anything.

In the context, virtualization works in the following way. You need to display 10000 data items. The screen only fits 15 UI elements. The system-provided VirtualizingStackPanel create ~17 UI elements, reuse those elements as user scrolls through your list. When the UI element goes offscreen, the panel "frees" the UI element (you can interfere if you want, see `ClearContainerForItemOverride` method). and prepares it for the later reuse (again, you can interfere if you want, see `PrepareContainerForItemOverride`). If more elements is needed (e.g. because the data items are becoming smaller), new UI elements are created.

The whole point is you have 10000 virtual items, while only ~17 actual item, hence virtualization.

In your code however, I see

```
public interface IVirtualizable
{
    FrameworkElement View { get; }
}
```

which means you have 1-to-1 relation between your data items and UI elements. UI elements are expensive, they own GPU textures and other system resources. That's why you're suffering from performance issues as you add more elements.

Reimplementing VirtualizingStackPanel is hard. It has 3-4 times more code then your MyVirtualizingPanel class. Fortunately you don't need to, it's already here in the framework, and it's pretty versatile. If you don't like list boxes due to its selected/not selected stuff, use plain ItemsControl, with ItemContainer set to VirtualizingStackPanel.

Comment: Thanks for the meaningful reply. 
I don't entirely agree with your points. Indeed my virtualizing panel doesn't recycle containers, but the virtualization is in place. IVirtualizable.View (which is Canvas in all my implementations of IVirtualizable) is only accessed by panel when corresponding element is in loaded state. So, implementer of the interface can set the view=null on unload and reinstantiate it on load.

Comment: I'm half way of identifying problems I described in the question and actually tend to think my approach is going to work. Will come back with results.